# Terminate long running task inside background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I have a task that compress an image, which use many many loops inside it:

```
private void writeCompressedData() {
    int i, j, r, c, a, b;
    loat[][] inputArray;

    for (r = 0; r < minBlockHeight; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < minBlockWidth; c++) {
            xpos = c * 8;
            pos = r * 8;
            for (comp = 0; comp < jpegObj.numberOfComponents; comp++) {
                inputArray = (float[][]) jpegObj.components[comp];

                 for (i = 0; i < jpegObj.VsampFactor[comp]; i++) {
                     for (j = 0; j < jpegObj.HsampFactor[comp]; j++) {
                         xblockoffset = j * 8;
                         yblockoffset = i * 8;
                         for (a = 0; a < 8; a++) {
                             for (b = 0; b < 8; b++) {
                                 // Process some data and put to inputArray
                             }
                         }

                         // Encode Huffman block 
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

I run this method inside a normal thread like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        writeCompressedData();
    }
});
```

Or run inside a background worker thread

```
TaskExecutor.queueRunnable(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        writeCompressedData();
    }
});
```

The problem is: this method sometimes go wrong and cause **infinite loops** when receive invalid input. In that case, it will run forever and **hurt the CPU even when the device's screen turn off** which increase device's temperature (and if I use worker thread it also blocks other tasks inside waiting queue).

I think I need to set a timeout to terminate long running task. What's the best way to achieve this in normal Java thread? Does RxJava support it?

---

I know what I need to fix is the "wrong" method, not just terminate it. But for the big apps, it's hard to control other developer's code, and the first thing I need is avoid affecting users.

Comment: If possible you could use a foreground service. They are designed to give the user the awareness of some process running in the background and the choice to stop it when they don't want it anymore. Just using some kind of timeout seems like big compromise to me.

Comment: Because this is just small/quick task (only when error it became big), so start new service seem's too big for me.

Comment: @nhoxbypass please share how did you end up doing this, also try out the rx-approach shared

Answer (score 3):

You'd need some form of cooperative cancellation, say checking `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` inside one or more of the nested loops.

```
for (/* ... */) {
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) return;

    for (/* ... */) {

        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) return;

        for (/* ... */) {
            // the tightest loop
        }             
    }
}
```

Then when you run the method, keep the `Thread`/`Future` and call `interrupt`/`cancel(true)`:

```
backgroundTask = new Thread(() -> method());
backgroundTask.start();
// ...
backgroundTask.interrupt();

backgroundFuture = executorService.submit(() -> method());
// ...
backgroundFuture.cancel(true);
```

In RxJava this would look something like this:

```
backgroundDisposable = Completable.fromAction(() -> method())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // dedicated thread recommended
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(() -> { /* done */ }, e -> { /* error */ });

// ...
backgroundDisposable.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Java `ExecutorService` with timeout and `Future` to fix this problem. See this [post](https://www.callicoder.com/java-callable-and-future-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to run such code in different process. Even the process crashed the main process will be un-impacted.

Comment: But this will cause context-switching cost.

Answer (score 0):

My Approach is with using **RxJava** and more specifically using **`Timeout`** operator of RxJava, Here is the gist of the code, After 5 seconds the onError will be called as there is no emission of an item within the previous 5 seconds,

```
private void timeOutObserver() {

        Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) {
                emitter.onNext("A");
            }
        })
                .timeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        Log.d("-@-", "subscribed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s) {
                        Log.d("-@-", "on next " + s);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d("-@-", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.d("-@-", "on complete");
                    }
                });
    }
```

For more working on TimeOut operator refer [this](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeout.html),

Comment: @nhoxbypass in your case for the example to work,replace the emitter in the success case of the compression code, by default if there is no emission within the  prescribed time it will throw an error and the excution will be stopped, Also important is to fine tune the time out based on the platform like if the platform is android the timeout will be within ANR is thrown.